# How to find the double integral limits of this problem after using Jacobian transformation?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, jacobian

$$\int_{y=0}^{y=1} \int_{x=y}^{x=2-y} \dfrac{x+y}{x^2}e^{x+y}\text{d}x\text{d}y, \quad x+y = u, \frac yx = v$$

The $u, v$ limits in the guide answer is from $0$ to $2$ for $u$ and $0$ to $1$ for $v$. But I can't find how it is done.

Comment: @Peter Phipps Thanks for edit.

Comment: Please try to use Mathjax for any other posts you make. There is a user-guide [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Have you tried to draw the domain?

Comment: @Andrei I did in terms of X and Y but still that didn't help me figure it out.

Comment: The largest value for $x+y$ is $3$, so something is wrong with your problem. Are you sure the upper limit of $x$ is $2$? I get the desired result only if the upper limit is $x=1$

Comment: @Andrei Well. The upper limit of x in my university book is written wrong. The correct one is in my guide answer which is 2 - y. I have edited the question to the correct one. Really sorry for this.

Comment: Are you still having problems with the corrected domain?

Comment: Yes. I still can't figure out why we got the u,v limits like this.

Answer (score 0):

Draw the domain in the $x-y$ plane. You can see that the limits for $x$ form some lines that happen to intersect where $x=y=1$. So the domain is the triangle between $(0,0), (1,1),(2,0)$. $u$ is along the direction perpendicular to the line from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$. You can split the domain into thin lines, parallel to the $(0,0)\to (1,1)$ line. Notice then that $u$ varies from $0+0=0$ (at the origin) to $1+1=2+0=2$ (the line in the triangle that is not going through the origin). In the perpendicular direction you are probably used to parametrize by $x-y$. But it's not necessary. A point on the perpendicular line can be parametrized by $u$ and **any** function  $f$ of $x$ and $y$, as long as you can extract the original $x$ and $y$ from $u$ and $f$. In this particular case, the function chosen is $u=\frac yx$. Then we need to look at the limits for $v$. When $(x,y)$ is on the $(0,0)\to(2,0)$ line, you have $y=0$ so $u=0$. When $(x,y)$ is on the $(0,0)\to(1,1)$ line, then $y=x$ so $u=1$.
[image]

Comment: I am confused. Firstly, why is u the line along (0,0) to (1,1). Secondly, I think you confused u and v in the end. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You were right, I swapped $x+y$ and $x-y$. Let me edit the answer, but the idea is the same.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by parametrizing with x-y or u ?

Comment: When you change variables, you replace two values, $x$ and $y$ with other two $u$ and $v$. This is similar to changing to polar coordinates $r$ and $\theta$. But you could also parametrize by $2r$ and $\theta$, or $r^2$ and $\theta/2$, or any such combination.

Comment: The answer just confused me more. I need a graphical representation. Also, please revise the answer well because there still seem to be some confusion between terms.

Comment: See if the picture helps